# User is null after login

Tags: php, yii2

Noob here. This project is for my workplace. I started to learn yii2. Basically I need to make an app that register a user, which it worked, a login, which it does not, and a logout. The problem is when I log in. My user returns null after I press login. I don't know why. Password validation is good. It finds the user, the id, the username, but after this it returns null. Why? I searched similar questions and it didn't helped me.
Here is my code:

SiteControler.php

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        //identity is null
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect('site/index');
        }
        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

User.php

```
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return self::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }
  

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }

    public function validateUsername($username)
    {
        
        return $this->username === $username;
    }
```

LoginForm.php

```
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do. I tried to do a setup in web.php and it did not help.